# How I can get event when remove item from Dashboard

Tags: extjs, dashboard

I have couple items on my Dashboard.

When I close some item (pushing close button on header panel of component ). Component removes from dashboard. But I don't see any events exept close component.

I found that in dashboard sources exists onRemoveItem method. 
To achive desired result I overrided that method.

Question: What event I need listen in dashboard panel to avoid overriding onRemoveItem method.

Comment: Try to listen remove event. This event will fire when we remove a component  from a container.

Comment: That is the problem. When you close item on dashboard, dashboard don't fire remove event.

Comment: then try to use beforeclose event

Comment: That event fires for item component not in Dashboard. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess you need to listen close event from dashboard-panel. Because as you see below dashboard doesn't fire any events( remove, close, etc ) when you close dashboard-panel.

[image]